# Showing a product attribute in admin sales orders overview page

Tags: magento-1.9, product, sales-order

How can i show a product attribute after the sku on the sales orders page the overview page when you goto sales->orders I want to add a column showing a product attribute in addition i need to be able to export this when exporting orders

I cant even find the template file for that page?

Answer (score 0):

I use [this module](https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/enhanced-admin-grids-editor.html).

Does what you want and more